# Modifying HTML File w/ Node and Dynamically Generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, fs

I'm writing an application that uses a mostly filled out HTML template, and nodemailer to send out an email. I need to *write* into the static html file at a particular point based on what happens with my webscraper.

The node has an id property that I'm calling "root" or "insert_root."

```
        ... MORE HTML ...
<tbody>
   <tr> 
     <td class="pc-fb-font" style="padding: 20px 20px; text-align: center; font-... 
        <div id="insert_root" style="margin-left: 20px"> 
         **Insert Here**
        </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
        ... THE REST OF THE HTML ...
```

What is the easiest and most reliable way of doing this? My html content that I would like to insert looks something like this:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; line-height: 1.42; letter-spacing: -0.4px; color: #151515;">Coons, Christopher A:</p>
<ul style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; padding: 0px; ">
   <li style="margin-left: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.42; letter-spacing: -0.4px; color: #151515;"><a href=https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/view/ptr/f06ca66b-6f1d-461e-990d-01e6bb206b51/>Periodic Transaction Report for 06/24/2019</a></li>
</ul>
<p style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; line-height: 1.42; letter-spacing: -0.4px; color: #151515;">Roberts, Pat:</p>
<ul style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; padding: 0px; ">
   <li style="margin-left: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.42; letter-spacing: -0.4px; color: #151515;"><a href=https://efdsearch.senate.gov/search/view/annual/ea3ce82e-f1e0-4f16-8498-79d02398f06c/>Annual Report for CY 2018</a></li>
</ul>
```

I figured that I could do something where I read the file using fs.readFile and write to it, but was wondering if there's a simpler solution that involves Cheerio or another HTML parser to get the exact root node, and somehow insert from there...thoughts?

Comment: Is your app using any templating engine which can render your vars and return the template? Using underscore etc? [_.template()](https://underscorejs.org/#template).

Answer (score 0):

As Lawrence pointed out, I should be using a template engine.

I put the <%= target %> and <%= targetTitle %> inside of my html file to accept the text. The code looks like this (within an async function):

```
const readFile = (fileName) => util.promisify(fs.readFile)(fileName, 'utf8');
const writeFile = (fileName, content) => util.promisify(fs.writeFile)(fileName, content, 'utf8');

let dynamicTtile = "titleIwanttoinsert";
let dynamicPost = "postIwantToInsert"

let html = await readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./emailContent/blankHtml/index.html"));

let tmpl = _.template(html);
let newHtml = tmpl({ target: dynamicHtml, targetTitle: dynamicTitle });

await writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'emailContent', 'emails', 'sent', 'index.html'), newHtml);
```